# How to make call using data from previous one and join result data together?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have an API which I can't modify. I have to use data as it is.

I want to join data from two separate requests where second request is based on data from the first one.

I have a working solution already but the code quality, in my opinion, is low so I want to know your opinion (and if you can provide: better, more reactive solution).

So, I have an **order** API that's receiving data:

`/orders` response:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    clientId: 201,
    // other data
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    clientId: 201,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    clientId: 11,
  }
]
```

In this response, I don't have data about the client name, so I have a second API where I can pass IDs of clients and then I got back:

`/clientsData?ids=201,11` response:

```
[
  {
    id:201,
    name: "Jon Doe"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: "Jack Sparrow"
  }
]
```

So, now I have a working code but as mentioned, in the beginning, I'm feeling it can be done in a better way. Please, note that the request should be done in correct order because I need clients IDs before I make a second API call.

Also, want to avoid making multiple (more than two [orders+clients]) requests to check client data.

Working code:

```
// API Call to get orders:
const result$ = this.http.get('/orders').pipe(
  mergeMap(
    orders => {
      const ids = orders
        .map(item => item.clientId)
        .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i) // remove duplicates
        .join(','); // get client ids into one string

      // Client IDs: 1,2,99,201
      // API call to check IDs:
      return this.http.get(`/clientsData?ids=${ids}`).pipe(
        mergeMap(clientsData => {
          // map over each client
          clientsData.forEach(client => {
            // then map over each order
            orders.forEach(order => {
              // and assign client name to order
              if (order.clientId === client.id) {
                order.clientName = client.name;
              }
            });
          });

          return of(orders); // observable
        })
      );
    }
  )
);

result$.subscribe(console.log);
```

I expect to get back Observable with merged data:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    clientId: 201,
    name: "Jon Doe"
    // other data
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    clientId: 201,
    name: "Jon Doe"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    clientId: 11,
    name: "Jack Sparrow"
  }
]
```

I want to avoid nested subscriptions and achieve the result in a reactive way.

Comment: If your code works, and you want a review on all aspects of the code, you should consider heading over to [codereview.se] and read their help center to find out if what you're asking is on topic there.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Code Review page :)